# If $A\subseteq \Bbb R $ is not compact, then there exists $f:A\to \Bbb R$ such that $f(x)>0$ and $\inf\{f(x)\} =0$.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

> Prove that if $A\subseteq \Bbb R $ is not compact, then there exists $f:A\to \Bbb R$, **$f $ continuous** such that $f(x)>0$ and $\inf\{f(x)\} =0$.

Attempt:

E: NVM, I forgot the continuous part.

As $A$ is no compact, then it's either not closed or unbounded. Either of these two imply that $A$ is infinite. I grab any countable subset of $A$ and make a sequence $(x_n)$, then define 
\begin{align}
f&:A\to \Bbb R\\
f&(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac 1 n, & x=x_n\text{ for some $n$.}\\
1, & \text{Else.}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

Then we have $f(x)>0$ and $\inf\{f(x)\}=0$.

Is this correct? For some reason I think I'm missing something. Hints are appreciated.

Comment: The question probably asks for a continuous function.

Comment: @N.S. ... You're right. I was caught up trying to think of a function that I forgot about that..

Comment: Use $f(x)=\frac1{1+x^2}$ for the unbounded case and $f(x)=(x-c)^2$ with suitable $c$ if $A$ is not closed.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen is the square in the second one needed? $c$ should be a limit of some sequence contained in $A$, which is not in it, right?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen never mind, it's because $f>0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As said by $\rm H$agen von $\rm E$itzen in the comments,

Let $A$ be closed. Then there exists a sequence $(y_n)\subseteq A$ with $y_n\to y \notin A$. Put $f(x)=(x-y)^2$ and the requirements are met.

Let $A$ be unbounded. Then $\frac {1}{1+x^2}$ works aswell.